# background calling using QuickBlox sdk Swift

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I need a help to implement background calling for my app. i have given permissions for vOIP and imported Pushkit and written delegate methods of it.

here are my delegate methods:

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
        print("didUpdate pushCredentials")
        guard let voipToken = registry.pushToken(for: .voIP) else {
            print("voip token and push token is nil")
            return
        }
        guard let deviceIdentifier = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString else {
            print("device id nil")
            return
        }
        let subscription = QBMSubscription()
        subscription.notificationChannel = .APNSVOIP
        subscription.deviceUDID = deviceIdentifier
        subscription.deviceToken = voipToken
        
        QBRequest.createSubscription(subscription, successBlock: { response, objects in
            print("[WaitingRoomVC] Create Subscription request - Success")
        }, errorBlock: { response in
            print("[WaitingRoomVC] Create Subscription request - Error")
        })
    }
```